# Redirect all urls with parameters to an specific page with same parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all the urls with parameters to a different url with same parameters.

For example: www.mysite.com/?q=about I need it going to www.mysite.com/index.php?q=about

I don't care about the parameters, but I need all of them going to index.php plus the same kind of parameters.

If I'm not wrong I should use RewriteRule but I'm not sure about how can I do it.

I was trying something like this, but it's not working:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, that can be done with RewriteRule directives but there many ways to do it, explain with an example what it is you want before the question gets closed. It's too general.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/(.*)/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php%1 [L]

To account for trailing slash, in index.php test the query like this:

<?php
if ( ($_GET['q'] == 'about') || ($_GET['q'] == 'about/') ){
//do stuff; 
}
?>
```

Of course `q=about` can be replaced with anything you want. i.e.  `search=apples`

Comment: I'm getting an Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Thanks Felipe for your help.
I tried your solution and it wasn't working.
But I found a solution that is working for me:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

Comment: It worked for me, but the important thing is now you know how to do it. Don't forget to modify `q` accordingly, in case you decide to use something else tomorrow in the query string.